# save result from dynamic query

Tags: sql, dynamicquery

Is there a way to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempLocal (tmpBanner nvarchar(255) )
SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO #TempLocal (tmpBanner) SELECT TOP 1 F1 FROM '+ @dbTable_Dollar
SELECT @Banner = tmpBanner FROM #TempLocal
DROP TABLE #TempLocal;
SELECT @Banner
```

Basically, I have a dynamic table parameter and I need to get the value from column 1 row 1.

thank,

KS

### SOLUTION

```
DECLARE @Banner nvarchar(255),
@chvSQL NVARCHAR(300)

SELECT @chvSQL = N'SELECT TOP 1 @Banner = [F1] from '+@dbTable_Dollar
EXEC sp_executesql @chvSQL, N'@Banner varchar(50) OUTPUT', @Banner OUTPUT
```

Comment: What implementation of sql?  In SQL Server you can use `sp_executesql` which has an optional output parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
DECLARE @Banner nvarchar(255),
@chvSQL NVARCHAR(300)

SELECT @chvSQL = N'SELECT TOP 1 @Banner = [F1] from '+@dbTable_Dollar
EXEC sp_executesql @chvSQL, N'@Banner varchar(50) OUTPUT', @Banner OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the result of your dynamic query on your temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempLocal (tmpBanner nvarchar(255) )
SET @Query = 'SELECT TOP 1 F1 FROM '+ @dbTable_Dollar

INSERT INTO #TempLocal (tmpBanner)
EXEC(@Query)

SELECT @Banner = tmpBanner FROM #TempLocal
```

Though I recommend you take a look at [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) first.

Comment: Thanks, I found a better way tho.